# How to debug "SSL connection error: ASN: bad other signature confirmation"?

Tags: linux, centos, mysql, ssl, mariadb

I have configured mariadb on CentOS7 with

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'tester'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'xxx' REQUIRE SSL;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'tester'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'xxx';
```

where I locally can connect with the client as expected.

Remotely it should only be possible to connect over SSL, but here I get

```
# mysql --ssl-ca=chain.cer -utester -p -h example.com
Enter password: 
ERROR 2026 (HY000): SSL connection error: ASN: bad other signature confirmation
```

That error I get regardless if I type the correct password or not.

On the server I have `/etc/my.cnf.d/server.cnf`

```
[mariadb-5.5]
ssl-ca=/etc/mysql/ssl/chain.cer
ssl-cert=/etc/mysql/ssl/example.pem
ssl-key=/etc/mysql/ssl/example.key
```

which is bought wildcard cert.

There is nothing logged in `/var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log` about this issue.

**Question**

How can I debug this?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18718339/getting-error-2026-hy000-ssl-connection-error-asn-bad-other-signature-conf#21622166 it seems to give an answer on how to do that for the same error message.